# Incorrect number of answers in profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

If I generate PDF of my resume (just by clicking generate or by attaching it to a job application) I get wrong number of answers:

> Stack Overflow – https://stackoverflow.com/users/2578489
>
> Written 7 answers. Active in php and git.

However on my profile page there are 91 Answers.

Profile: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/ruslanosipov

EDIT: Issue appeared after disabling and enabling again display stackoverflow account on my profile.

Comment: Hmm, strange. The number is correct for me. So I guess it's not a global issue.

Comment: FWIW, I've disabled and enabled the showing of my SO account on my own careers profile, and my # of written answers didn't change (although it's showing 968 answers rather than the 969 SO itself reports for whatever reason).

Comment: I'll forward this over to a dev and see what's going on.

Comment: @Matt the number isn't exactly real time, it updates a couple times per day on average, but if you are very active it will regularly appear different in between syncs.